# Dealing with global temp tables when they don't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got the following block of code:

```
DECLARE @TTable VARCHAR(MAX)= 'SELECT X.* ';
SELECT @TTable+='
INTO ##NewTemp1' + convert(varchar(6), @TStamp) + '
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM ##Temp1' + convert(varchar(6), @TStamp) + '
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM ##Temp2' + convert(varchar(6), @TStamp) + '
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM ##Temp3' + convert(varchar(6), @TStamp) + '
...
etc
...
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM ##Temp22' + convert(varchar(6), @TStamp) + '
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM ##Temp23' + convert(varchar(6), @TStamp) + '
) X'
PRINT(@TTable);
EXECUTE(@TTable);
```

The problem is, on occasion one (or more) of the temp tables won't get created.  When that happens, this block of code fails because it's trying to union a table that doesn't exist.

I know I can use the following line of code to determine if a temp table exists:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
```

but how can I integrate that into a string like I'm using above (@TTable) to check and make sure a table exists before unioning it?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to get rid of this mess altogether, but if you're going to insist on moving data around between dynamic global temporary tables then you'll need to build the string dynamically:

```
DECLARE @TTable VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT X.col1, X.col2'  -- Because we NEVER use SELECT *

SELECT @TTable += ' INTO ##NewTemp1' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), @TStamp) + -- You should probably put a format here
    ' FROM ('

IF (OBJECT_ID('##Temp1' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), @TStamp)) IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT @TTable += 'SELECT col1, col2 FROM ##Temp1' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), @TStamp) + '
UNION
'
...  Repeat for each temp table

SELECT @TTable += ' SELECT 1 AS col1, 1 AS col2 WHERE 1=0) X'
```

That last line is to avoid a `UNION` from dangling at the end because you don't know which temp tables might be there or not.